# Bluetooth is not working properly on Debian

Tags: debian, bluetooth

I have an ASUS nettop with Debian Jessie and just want to enable bluetooth there so it will be dicoverable and can discover other devices.

All bluetooth utilities showing that it is up and working, however neither `hcitool scan` can discover any devices nor I can discover nettop from my mobile phone.

```
bt-adapter -i
    [hci0]
      Name: ***
      Address: C8:FF:28:7F:**:**
      Alias: ***** [rw]
      Class: 0x104
      Discoverable: 1 [rw]
      DiscoverableTimeout: 0 [rw]
      Discovering: 1
      Pairable: 1 [rw]
      PairableTimeout: 0 [rw]
      Powered: 1 [rw]
      UUIDs: [PnPInformation, 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, AVRemoteControl, AVRemoteControlTarget]

hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: C8:FF:28:7F:**:**  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 183:5
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:5492 acl:0 sco:0 events:753 errors:0
    TX bytes:6869 acl:0 sco:0 commands:644 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x0d 0xfe 0xd8 0x7f 0x7b 0x8f
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: '****'
    Class: 0x000104
    Service Classes: Unspecified
    Device Class: Computer, Desktop workstation
    HCI Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Revision: 0x3101
    LMP Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Subversion: 0x1
    Manufacturer: Atheros Communications, Inc. (69)
```

In GUI Bluetooth settings windows is constantly in state of discovering
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwOQj.png)

Can anyone suggest what can be wrong with my device?

UPD: booting into Windows and switching on bluetooth did the trick.

Comment: I you have a dual-boot with windows this question might help:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/543821/bluetooth-not-working-properly-not-detecting-devices

Comment: Yep, that worked for me, just forgot to update the question